# WebSphere 8.5 :ESB is missing. How to start it together with WebSphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-esb

I installed BPM:

```
 ./imcl install \
 com.ibm.bpm.ESB.v85_8.6.0.20170918_1207, \
 com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5012.20170627_1018 \
 -repositories /u01/tmp/BPM/repository/repos_64bit/repository.config \
 -acceptLicense \
 -installationDirectory /u01/apps/IBM/BPM \
 -properties user.wasjava=java8 \
 -showVerboseProgress -log silentinstall.log
```

Than i created Deployment_Managed Profile:

```
./manageprofiles.sh  \
-create \
-adminPassword XXXXXXX \
-profileName Dmgr06 \
-cellName Cell03 \
-serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER \
-adminUserName wasadmin \
-enableAdminSecurity true \
-nodeName CellManager03 \
-profilePath /u01/apps/IBM/BPM/profiles/Dmgr06 \
-personalCertValidityPeriod 15 \
-signingCertValidityPeriod 15 \
-keyStorePassword XXXXXXXX \
-templatePath /u01/apps/IBM/BPM/profileTemplates/management/ \
-startingPort 10000 \
-isDefault
```

After This i run the startManager.sh command. I was expecting to see WebSphere and ESB up and running but i see only WebSphere:
[image]

How do i add the ESB?

Comment: You should configure your environment with the BPMConfig command - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFPJS_8.6.0/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.bpmesb.doc/topics/bpmcfg_sim_nd_lin_db2.html , not directly with manageprofiles.

Comment: many thanks Gas. Can you give me an example how to use the BPMConfig for deployment manager profile?